# R Key Lookup on datatable performance slower than dataframe by filter?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Starting off on a project, I am doing some performance checks to decide on whether to use mainly DataFrames with dplyr or DataTables. One thing my project will require is repeated row lookups in different contexts using a row ID column value (not the index).

After doing some reading, it seemed that the datatables package's datatable with a properly defined key would provide the best performance. But from my checks below, it seems that filtering on a dataframe is faster?

I surmise from [this post](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3036) that using matrices are the fastest way of assigning values, but I am surprised that the two approaches using dataframes in my code below are both faster than datatables. Matrices are the fastest of all.

I am new to datatables (and R in general), so can someone point out what I am doing wrong here and how to improve the code for datatables so the performance matches that of dataframes?

```
library("data.table")  
library("microbenchmark")


# Create testing data set with character IDs - here we only have an ID
# column and one column, but in real application there will be many
#columns
dt <- data.table(ID = paste0("A", seq(1,5000, by = 1)),
                 Value = runif(5000,1,100))
setkey(dt, ID) #Set the key on the data table

#Get the table as a data frame
df <- as.data.frame(dt)
rownames(df) <- df$ID  #Set row names on data frame

# Get a matrix version -
matx <- matrix(df$Value, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = 1)
rownames(matx) <- df$ID #Set row names on matrix

id <- "A567"

dt.by.key = function(id.value) {
  return(dt[.(id.value)]$Value)
}

df.by.filter = function(id.value) {
  return(df[df$ID == id.value, ]$Value)
}

df.by.rowname = function(id.value) {
  return(df[[id.value, "Value"]])
}

matrix.by.rowname = function(id.value) {
  return(matx[[id.value, 1]])
}

microbenchmark(
  dt.by.key(id), 
  df.by.filter(id),
  df.by.rowname(id),
  matrix.by.rowname(id),
  check = "equal",
  times = 1000
  )
```

Results below:
[image: output of microbenchmark]

Note that I am testing the lookup/filter on the DataFrame using filtering on the ID column and on the Name which is mapped to the ID column. It seems the matrix lookup is fastest.

**Note**: At first I presented my performance testing code using sytem.time with for loops. Most of the comments below focused on the for loops instead of the main question, so I have refactored my example code. Thanks to @r2evans for suggesting the use of microbenchmark.

Any advice **related specifically to improving performance of lookup on datatables** is much appreciated!

Comment: Any way you could make this reproducible? Obviously we don't have "test_data_lookup.csv"

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do, but vectorization is often the answer for better R performance. It's not clear to me why you need a loop for these approaches. These timings seem extraordinarily slow for 5000 rows of data. https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/

Comment: @JonSpring - the for loops are just to allow for more repeats so I can get more reliable performance indexing.  Why repeated lookup then: Let's say I am using apply() on another data table with a custom function - then I will need to extract the key for the current row (in the apply function) and use lookup on key in another dataset (e.g. one that contains meta-data etc). So I cannot avoid repeated lookup on key completely - hence my need to pick the best approach. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: If you are using `for` loops for "performance indexing", how about using `bench::mark` or the `microbenchmark` package for benchmarking? A `for` loop here seems to be obfuscating the real intent.

Comment: @JonSpring - I have modified the code to create the data.table and data.frame without having to read from file. Many thanks for your interest in my question.

Comment: What is the result you want? Your current code for `test.df.by.filter`, for instance, overwrites a vector `val` 101 times (one for each element in `ids`), each time extracting the Value that corresponds to that ID and doubling it, but then throwing it away and starting over with the next ID. If the goal is to get the subset that matches the order of `ids` and double the values, you might do something like this in dplyr: `data.frame(ID = ids) %>% left_join(df) %>% mutate(Value = Value * 2)`

Comment: @JonSpring - these methods are just stubs to test performance. In this context, they are not supposed to do anything except check the speed of retrieving a value by key.

Comment: If you only have a lookup table with one column (or just a vector), simply use `dt[ID %in% ids, Value := 2 * Value, ID]` and you can optimize with `fastmatch` library using `%fin%` instead which incredibly speeds up multiple lookups. Usually if you want a lookup and use other values from the lookup table, then use a join.

Comment: [ carries an overhead. Instead of subsetting row by row, subset all rows you need and work on them. This is what we can call a vectorized approach.

Comment: @r2evans - thanks for your suggestion. I have modified my example accordingly

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg - thanks for your suggestion. Any chance you can expand that and post it as an answer showing results using microbenchmark? You can just use my code but replace my existing indexing on datatable with your suggestion? If it answers my question I will mark yours as the answer.

Comment: @Fritz45 You changed your user case quite a lot from a "look-up-table" like question towards a single value lookup, returning a single value. I would not consider my approach the answer for the example you have currently provided.